# iOS Widget like screen in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

We are looking to build an iOS widget like screen in flutter. On an iphone if you swipe right a scrollable widget screen appears with application info like News, Stocks etc.

Each widget is a transparent-like rounded box, I'll attach a screenshot. Im struggling with how to design this, I thought maybe a listview with containers but im not sure and cant get the widgets to look right.

### SCREENSHOT

[image: Widget Screen iOS]

Comment: please make your question specific

Comment: Scrolling widget based page u can get to anywhere in the app by swiping right. Each widget is separated and a rounded edge container exactly like the screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the Opacity of your `listTiles` using the `Opacity` widget, and as for the rounded corners you can use the `borderRadius` propery of any `Container` like `SizedBox` and `ClipRRect`.